# Redirect subprocess.Popen stderr to console

Tags: python

I am executing a make command using subprocess.Popen. But when the make fails I do not get the exact error from make and th escript just continues to run. How do I get the script to stop and show the console exactly the output of the make command

```
def app(self, build, soc, target):
    command = "make BUILD=%s SOC=%s TARGET=%s" % (build, soc, target)
    subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=False,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Comment: What (python related) error do you get when it fails?

Comment: The simplest way is to use Python 3.4, if possible, and replace the call to `subprocess.popen()` with `subprocess.run()`. That returns an object that contains the return code and result of stdout and stderr as a list of strings.

Comment: @Tom Dalton Actually the problem is it just continues and doesn't throw an exception. Then later on in the script it relies on the make command passing and here is when the script fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try replacing:

```
subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

with:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.communicate()
print p.returncode
```

And let us know what the printed output looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the make output to actually go to the console, don't use `subprocess.PIPE` for stdout/stderr.  By default, the called process will use the Python process's stdout/stderr handles.  In that case, you can use the `subprocess.check_call()` function to raise a `subprocess.CalledProcessError` if the called process returns a non-zero exit code:

```
subprocess.check_call(command.split())
```

However, if you need to capture the make output for use in your script, you can use the similar `subprocess.check_output()` function:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(command.split(), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    output = e.output
    # error handling here
```

Note that this combines the stdout and stderr output into a single value.  If you need them separately, you would need to use the `subprocess.Popen` constructor in conjunction with the `.communicate()` method and manually checking the `returncode` attribute of the `Popen` object:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0:
    # raise exception or other error handling here
```